# Postfix not able to receive mails from external domains

Tags: email, postfix-mta, centos5

Problem is that I able to send mails from my myname@mydomain.com to outside domains but all mails coming from outside (myname@gmail.com) are is not reaching my domain mail ids. I am not sure where I made mistake.

This is my postfix main.cf :

```
inet_protocols = all
   myhostname = mail.changed.com
   mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
   message_size_limit = 30720000
   virtual_alias_domains = 
   virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf,    mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
   virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
   virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
   virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
   virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
   virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
   smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
   smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
   smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
   broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
   smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
   smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks , permit_sasl_authenticated,       reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_sender_domain,                          
                reject_unknown_recipient_domain,                               
                reject_non_fqdn_sender,                               
                reject_non_fqdn_recipient,                         
                permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,                           
                reject_unauth_destination,                             
                reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,                          
                reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
          check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:60000

   smtpd_use_tls = yes
   smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/postfix.pem
   smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/postfix.pem
   virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
   virtual_maildir_extended = yes
   virtual_transport = dovecot
   dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
   smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
```

I have strong feeling that something is wrong in **smtpd_recipient_restrictions**

451 4.3.5 server configuration error for all the gmail ids

Answer (score 4):

Fixed:

I commented the below line and the issue is resolved. I am able to recieve mails from externals domains now.
**#check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:60000** in smtpd_recipient_restrictions